# chi-square test for multiple features in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sample dataframe like this

```
m_list = ['male','male','female','female']
whiskey_list = ['alcohol','no_alcohol','alcohol','no_alcohol']
f1 = [273,62,60,7]
f2 = [276,61,57,8]
l = [m_list,whiskey_list,f1,f2]
test_df = pd.DataFrame(l).T
test_df.columns = ['gender','drink_category','f1','f2']


    gender  drink_category  f1  f2
0   male    alcohol         273 276
1   male    no_alcohol      62  61
2   female  alcohol         60  57
3   female  no_alcohol      7   8
```

I want to see if there is any relationship between the 2 categories - `gender` and `drink_category` using a Chi-square test. For these purposes, I want to build a contingency table for each feature that ranges from `f1,f2....fn` and then compute `p-values` for each feature.

The example here has only 2 features `f1` and `f2` but in general I have many.

When I am processing `f1`, then my contingency table would look like -

```
gender   alcohol   no_alcohol
male      273        62
female    60         7
```

Then I would compute p-value for `f1`.

When I am processing `f2`, then my contingency table would look like -

```
gender   alcohol   no_alcohol
male      276        61
female    57         8
```

How can I compute this using `pandas` and `scipy` libraries ?

At the end, I want a dataframe where I have p-values for each feature `f1` to `fn`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use scipy.stat's [`chi2_contingency`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chi2_contingency.html) to get the p values for the contingency tables build with pandas' [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) function.

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import chi2_contingency

test_df = pd.DataFrame({'gender': ['male','male','female','female'],
                        'drink_category': ['alcohol','no_alcohol','alcohol','no_alcohol'],
                        'f1': [273,62,60,7],
                        'f2': [276,61,57,8]})

p = pd.Series()
for feature in [c for c in test_df.columns if c.startswith('f')]:
   _,p[feature],_,_ = chi2_contingency(test_df.pivot('gender','drink_category',feature))

print(p)
```

Output:

```
f1    0.155699
f2    0.339842
dtype: float64
```